# Is there any reason to avoid using bigint for a surrogate primary key?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I am designing a database and I have a number of tables that could potentially outgrow the maximum size of a standard 32-bit int.  However, it will likely be years before this happens and there is no guarantee that it will ever even actually happen.

However, given that there is a chance it could happen, should I go ahead and choose bigint for the primary key?  What are the implications of doing it now vs changing it later?  Is it even possible to convert an int primary key to a bigint later on, and if so, how difficult is it and is it feasible?

Comment: For last question [Converting int primary key to bigint in Sql Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461205/converting-int-primary-key-to-bigint-in-sql-server). If your table will be so big, think about partitioning or archiving old data.

Comment: assuming you're using unsigned 32bit ints, then going with an unsigned 64bit int will "waste" 2 bytes per record, 8gigabytes total, until you'd go past the 32bit boundary. if your server can't handle 8gigs of 'wasted' space, then go with 32bit.

Comment: SQL Server supports [unsigned integers](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/515502/unsigned-integer-data-type)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going BIG will cost you on storage and performance - especially if it means your foreign key references also have to be BIGINT.

Looking "years" ahead isn't necessarily a prudent thing to do. Most (not all) IT projects are expected to recover their costs within 3 years. You will most likely have to contend with plenty of changes and upgrades over the years and if your database has grown so much in that time then it shouldn't be so much effort to change an INT to a BIGINT if and when you need to. By then maybe your business and the database world in general will have moved on and it won't be an issue any more. [YAGNI](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/early.html) rules.

Comment: _it shouldn't be so much effort to change an INT to a BIGINT_ I can only surmise you haven't actually had to do this.  Changing the column is easy, sure.  Finding all the places that column was used (e.g. stored procedures, functions, etc.) and then patching that up as well can be a considerable effort.

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't a reason to avoid it per se. It does take more storage space though. If this is the primary key column you can't change the datatype unless you first drop the primary key. Assuming you name your primary key constraint this is fairly simple. You don't have to create a new column and do all that hocus pocus nonsense like in the comment from lad2025.

```
create table IntTest
(
    MyID int identity 
    , SomveValue uniqueidentifier
    , constraint IntTest_PK primary key clustered (MyID)
)

insert IntTest
select NEWID()
from sys.all_columns

alter table IntTest drop constraint IntTest_PK

alter table IntTest alter column MyID BigInt

alter table IntTest add constraint IntTest_PK primary key clustered (MyID)
```

Comment: we just found out that our bigint PKs are adding 6 seconds to our queries.  Looks like the science has come in and squashed our using bigints for PKs.